# In Rust, how to "add" `flatten" to Option<Option<T>>?

Tags: generics, rust

How can I "add" a `flatten()` method to `Option<U>`, which would only typecheck if and only if `U` is an `Option<T>`, or more simply to add it to `Option<Option<T>>`? Naively, I am trying to write the following, which doesn't compile:

```
impl Option<Option<T>> {
    fn flatten(&self) -> Option<T> {
        match self {
            None => None,
            Some(v) => v,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Some(Some(1));
    let y = x.flatten();
    println!("{:?}", y);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't write inherent implementations (what you're trying) to types you didn't define, due to coherence (if you could, how do you know someone *else* hasn't also defined something called `flatten`?).

Instead, you need to define and implement a trait with the method you want.  Anywhere you want the method, you use the trait:

```rust
trait Flatten<T> {
    fn flatten(self) -> Option<T>;
}

impl<T> Flatten<T> for Option<Option<T>> {
    fn flatten(self) -> Option<T> {
        match self {
            None => None,
            Some(v) => v,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Some(Some(1));
    let y = x.flatten();
    println!("{:?}", y);
}
```

Also note that I changed the subject of the method from `&self` to `self`: you can't move out of a borrow (*especially* not an immutable one), so taking `self` by reference doesn't really make sense here.

Comment: Note that since rust 1.40 there is a [flatten](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.flatten) function for `Option<Option<T>>`.